# probability of accidental collision between 2 populations

Tags: statistics

We have a system by which some existing members are deemed "Do not use." Unfortunately, our 'unique' identifier is only 3.65 million permutations.

-DNU is approximately 800 and growing at a rate of 1 per day.
-Main population is approximately 30,000
-New and returning entrants arrive at a rate of approximately 275 per day

Given the relatively small number of permutations, how do I determine the incidence of accidental collisions where a new or returning entrant has the same identifier as a member of the DNU?

Comment: Are you looking to detect  a collision, or to compute the likelihood?  To detect them, I would just keep a file with 3.65 million entries, one for each identifier, and put an entry in when you use  that identifier.

Comment: Ross, We are trying to determine the probability of an accidental collision between a new entrant with an active member of the main population, and the probability of a misidentification of the same entrant with a member of the smaller DNU population. The "UID" is a combination of last 4 SSN + Birth month + birth day (excluding year), ergo, we have limited uniqueness. My apologies for not being very clear.

Answer (score 0):

For one new entrant, the chance of a collision is just the number of existing entries divided by the number of possible IDs, here 3.65 million.  You may be thinking of the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) where the chance of a collision is much higher than you think when you start with a pool of entries.  If you have already verified no collision among $n$ entries and want to add the $n+1^{st}$ the collision probability is as I have said.

Comment: Do bear in mind, IDs are not assigned on entry, they are defined by partial SSN and partial Birth date.

Comment: I am assuming the pieces are randomly distributed among the legal values.  This would mean that given two entrants the chance that the SSNs match is $1/10,000$ if you use four digits.  If you believe the uniformity assumption it doesn't matter that the ID is defined instead of random.